# What is going on behind /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Tags: apache-2.2

I have multiple processes named "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start". And some of them consume all CPU power.
Is there any way to know what exactly they are doing? (E.g. what script is running)
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `mod_status` -- it'll tell you what your worker processes (or threads) are up to.